# Average of a disrete and a continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

Find the cumulative distribution of $W$. Is the random variable discrete or continuous ?
How to find the p.d.f or p.m.f. for the random variable. FInd $E[(W-1)^2]$.

We have,
\begin{align*}
F_W(w)&=P(W\le w)\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^4 P(Y\le 2w-X|X=x).P(X=x)\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^4 F_Y(2w-x)f(x)
\end{align*}

So, c.d.f. of $W$ is differentiable.

How to check whether $W$is discrete or continuous ? How to find the mass/density function for $W$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\rhd$ First, some correction in your computation :

\begin{align*}
F_W(w)&=P(W\le w)\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^4 P(Y\le 2w-X|X=x).P(X=x)\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^4 F_Y(2w-x).P(X=x)\\
&=F_Y(2w-0).P(X=0)+F_Y(2w-1).P(X=1)+F_Y(2w-2).P(X=2)+F_Y(2w-3).P(X=3)+F_Y(2w-4).P(X=4)\\
&=F_Y(2w-0).\dfrac{1}{2}+F_Y(2w-1).0+F_Y(2w-2).0+F_Y(2w-3).0+F_Y(2w-4).\dfrac{1}{2}\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2} . \left(F_Y(2w) + F_Y(2w-4)\right).
\end{align*}

$\rhd$ Here, as $Y$ follows an exponentiel distribution, its c.d.f $F_Y$ is $\mathcal{C}^{1}$ on $\mathbb{R}^*$ and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore  $F_W$ is $\mathcal{C}^{1}$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0,2\}$ and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. This tells us the $Y$ is a continuous random variable. To find its probability density function, you just have to find the derivative of $F_W$, knowing that the derivative of $F_Y$ is $f$.

Comment: (Q1)How $F_W$ is $\mathcal C^1$ n $\Bbb R^2\setminus \{0,2\}$ ? I mean why we remove two points $0$ and $2$ ? (Q2) After derivative I got, $f_W(w)=\frac 12 e^{-w}+\frac 12 e^{-(w-2)}$. But I am unable to determine the range of $w$. Can you please help at this point ?

Comment: - $F_Y$ is not $C^1$ at $0$, therefore $w \mapsto F_Y(2w)$  is not $C^1$ at $0$ and $w \mapsto F_Y(2w-4)$  is not $C^1$ when $2w-4 = 0$, i.e. when $w=2$.

- Be careful when you take the derivative : the derivative of $x \mapsto F_Y(x)$ is *not* $x \mapsto  (1/2).e^{-x/2}$, because $f$ is $0$ when $x <0$. Thus you have 4 cases (in reality 3) to consider : when $2w <0$ and $2w-4 < 0$, when $2w \geq 0$ and$2w-4 <0$, when $2w <0$ and $2w-4 \geq 0$ (impossible), and when $2w \geq 0$ and $2w -4 \geq 0$. This will give you 3 intervals on which to compute $f_W$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much❤️